# Jquery incorrect children number XML parser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently I have encountered problems in writing a small XML parser in JavaScript using Jquery. The code which I am using for accomplish this task is as follows :

```
     /*Private */
 var XMLObject=$.parseXML(dataXml);
 var $XMLObject=$(XMLObject); 

 var questionNumber=0;
 // array of XML objects 
 var questionsXML= new Array();

 /** Html questions */ 
 //array of strings
 var questionsHTML= new Array();
 /*********************
  * Constructor       *
  *********************/

 a=$XMLObject.find("questions"); 
 a.children().each( function () {
     console.log( "XML : " +  new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this));
     questionsXML[questionNumber]=this;
     questionNumber++; 
 });


this.getXML=function () {
    var out = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this.XMLObject);
    return out;
}

this.getQuestionNumber=function() { 
    return questionNumber; 
}

// This function returns the question sequentially. 
this.getQuestion=function() { 
}

Test function  :

    function testXML () { 
        var xml ="XML see later"
        var Obj= new XMLQuestions(xml); 
        console.log("Question Number: " + Obj.getQuestionNumber());
    }
```

I don't understand why the number of children returned is 3 when it should be 2. As it is stated in the Jquery documentation children function should only check the first level of the XML tree.

The XML used as Test is the follwing one :

```
<questionnaire>
  <questions>
      <question id="1">
          <number></number>
          <title>Q1</title>
          <answers >
              <answer type="TextInput">
                  <result>ss</result>
                  <questions>
          <title>Hidden</title>
         </questions>
              </answer>
          </answers>
      </question>
    <question id="2">
    <title>Q2</title>
    </question>
  </questions>
</questionnaire>
```

as you can see the number of question's children is two.

The results I have got so fare are :

```
XML : <question id="1">           <number/>           <title>Q1</title>           <answers>               <answer type="TextInput">                   <result>ss</result>                     <questions>                     <title>Hidden</title>                   </questions>                </answer>           </answers>          </question> question.js:24
XML : <question id="2">         <title>Q2</title>       </question> question.js:24
XML : <title>Hidden</title> question.js:24
Question Number: 3
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Any specific reason you are writing your own parser? There so many parsers already available.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't calling `this.XMLObject` cause error where there is no such property? You're defining `var XMLObject` which isn't the same as `this.XMLObject`;

Also calling `this.$XMLObject` when the actual variable isn't a property should rise an exception aswell.

Another thing: try using `questionsXML.push(this)` instead of having to increment the variable `questionNumber`. And to return the count use `return questionsXML.length`.

Apart from that I think your code should return the right value. Or maybe there are more `children` (inner nodes/values).

XML to test:

```
<questionnaire>
    <questions>
        <question id="1">
            <number></number>
            <title>Q1</title>
            <answers>
                <answer type="TextInput">
                <result>ss</result>
            </answers>
        </question>
        <question id="2">
            <number></number>
            <title>Q1</title>
            <answers>
                <answer type="TextInput">
                <result>sSSs</result>
            </answers>
        </question>
    </questions>
</questionnaire>
```

Comment: If this is the actual XML you're using it shouldn't be working at all... The markup is kind of messed up. Can you try mine and give us the result?